# How to get the first visible html element in a WebBrowser?

Tags: html, wpf, dom, webbrowser-control

I'm using the .Net 4.0 WebBrowser (from System.Windows.Controls). In my application the user can modify the html data and the webbrowser shows an update. The application should then automatically scroll to the previous element that was displayed.

I'm using WPF / c# 4.0 on windows 7.

In detail:

- In the code I call WebBrowser.NavigateToString(htmlData1);
- the user scrolls to an arbitrary position
- the user changes (somehow) the html document
- **now I would like to find (and remember) the first html element that is displayed**
- I call WebBrowser.NavigateToString(htmlData2);
- now I would like to use the memorized element to automatically scroll the html document (I know that there is IHTMLElement.scrollIntoView() to do this)

So the question is: How do I get the first visible html element in a WebBrowser?

You may say that the updated html will not have the memorized element anymore. Right. But I have timestamps in the document and will use the memorized html element to find the best position in the new html doc.

Comment: Multiple elements could cover an arbitrary position if they have no border, padding or spacing, e.g. h3, p, span, a, img. Which one you plan to use as the anchor? Also how do you identify the element if it does not have an id? Finding the pattern of a dynamic page requires some time reverse engineering the server side code.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the right method to use. There are actually two possibilities to retain the scroll position when the document is being refreshed.

Assume the following members:

```
WebBrowser _browser;
HTMLDocument HtmlDoc { get { return (HTMLDocument)_browser.Document; } }
```

(1) If the document didn't really change (in my example only changed in style) I use the current scroll position to auto-scroll after an update:

- before refresh:

  ```
  _scrollPos = ((IHTMLElement2)(HtmlDoc.documentElement)).scrollTop;
  ```
- after refresh:

  ```
  HtmlDoc.parentWindow.scrollTo(0, _scrollPos);
  ```

(2) If the document has changed I use the left upper element of my document (that is of known structure)

- before refresh:

  ```
  IHTMLElement el = HtmlDoc.elementFromPoint(50, 0);
  ```

  Do some magic with that el (requires knowledge of the doc) and remember some string that can be used to search for the best element after the update.

  ```
  string beforeRefresh = fromElement(el);
  ```
- after refresh use the remembered string and search for the best html element in the reloaded html doc.

  ```
  IHTMLElement newEl = fromString(beforeRefresh);
  newEl.scrollIntoView(true);
  ```

So the actual method I was missing was elementFromPoint(). The rest is "custom logic".